# Is it better to use a router's openVPN implementation or to build my own?

Tags: vpn

My router has an openVPN server built in which I use. My only real need is for me to be able to access my home network so I can connect to my ZNC and media server. I was thinking about either putting openvpn on my raspi or on my main home server. Would there be any benefit or drawback to having the server behind my home router rather than on the router itself?

Comment: Probably no difference to be honest. Has the router firmware been updated to resolve the heartbleed OpenSSL vulnerability? The problem with using an internal server as your VPN server is how do then intend to access the rest of your network? Unless your VPN server is a DHCP server or relay agent for your LAN you won't be able to communicate with your other devices...

Comment: If you're able to update your router firmware or are not entirely bothered about the heartbleed vulnerability then you can keep using your router. They do a good job for home/soho setups. If you want to use a server other than your router, don't forget you'll need to forward the relevant ports to your server and give it a static IP on your LAN.